# Using jQuery ajax() with Perl causes flicker on success

Tags: jquery, ajax, perl

I'm trying to update some existing code that normally runs a Perl script which outputs a dynamically generated html page for messages, etc.  Ultimately, my end result is to simply update a `div` with the output of the Perl file rather than sending the user to a new page.

I've been down a couple roads trying to find the best way to do this.  After failing to find a way to do this on the Perl side, I'm now looking at jQuery `ajax()`.

Here is what I have so far and it's partially working:

**Perl:**

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
# =====================================================================

print "Content-type: text/html \n\n";
print "<p>Hello</p>";
```

**HTML:**

```html
<form id="myForm" action="#">
    <input type="submit" value="click me" />
</form>

<div id="message"></div>
```

**jQuery/JavaScript:**

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myForm').submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/cgi-bin/myPerl.cgi',
                async: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#message').html(data);
                } 
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**1)**  When I click the button, the `#message` `div` only flashes the message for a second and then it goes blank.  Why is that happening?  This is my primary question.

I also do not fully understand all the settings in `.ajax()` despite my reading of [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

**2)**  It only works at all if I use `async: false`, otherwise with `true` or leaving this setting out, I get a *"failed to load resource"* error.  Can somebody explain.

**3)**  Is there a better way to do this?  PHP?  I just want to dynamically update a `div` with the message coming from the Perl file, avoiding page refreshes or new pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `return false` or `e.preventDefault()` to the submit event.

```
    $('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/cgi-bin/myPerl.cgi',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#message').html(data);
            } 
        });
        // return false;
    });
```

Comment: Doh!  Makes total sense and I should have realized that!  Thank-you... that fixed it.  Any thoughts on the other part of my question?

Comment: That should have fixed #1 and #2. I'm not positive what you mean in #3

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need `async: false` anymore.

Comment: You're right... #2 is a non-issue now.  For #3, I'm simply asking if this is the best approach for dynamically updating content (without a refresh/reload) with output coming from Perl.  I mean, ajax is the only way, right?

Comment: Ajax is the only way (unless you consider hidden iframes an option, \*shudders\*. As far as Perl vs PHP, if your script is in Perl, you should do it with Perl.